# how can i get list of book from Wikibooks with SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

how can i get list of book from Wikibooks with SPARQL query fo example :
PREFIX  dbo:http://dbpedia.org/ontology/
PREFIX dba:http://dbpedia.org/ontology/
SELECT  ?author ?name ?label ?text ?title ?isbn ?publisher ?literaryGenre ?pages WHERE
{?book   a                 dbo:Book.
?book   dbo:author         ?author.
?book   dbo:numberOfPages  ?pages.
?book   dbp:title          ?title.
?book   dba:isbn          ?isbn.
?book   dba:publisher        ?publisher.

FILTER regex(?title , "java") .
}

Comment: I'm wondering whether you know that Wikibooks is **not** Wikipedia and DBpedia is based on Wikipedia?!

Comment: And then, why do you have two prefixes `dbo` and `dba` for the same namespace `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` ? I really suggest to understand what you're doing and hwta the query does instead of copy and paste from some other sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering whether you know that Wikibooks is not Wikipedia and DBpedia is based on Wikipedia?!

And then, why do you have two prefixes `dbo` and `dba` for the same namespace http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ ? I really suggest to understand what you're doing and what the query does instead of copy and paste from some other sources. SPARQL and RDF tutorials might help, and also the official documentation is useful.

Next issue, you `SELECT` variables `?name`, `?label`, `?text` and `?literaryGenre` which are not bound in a triple pattern in the `WHERE` part. It's also not clear what you expect to get for `?text`. The whole text of the book?! For sure, this won't exist, think about copyrights.
And what would be the difference between `?name` and `?title`? I don't think that `dbp:title` is the appropriate property here, see

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT count(*) WHERE {
?book a dbo:Book ;
      dbp:title ?title. 
}
```

which returns `19` only.

My suggestion:

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

SELECT * WHERE {
 ?book a dbo:Book .
 ?book dbo:author ?author . 
 OPTIONAL { ?book dbo:numberOfPages ?pages }
 OPTIONAL { ?book dbo:isbn ?isbn }
 OPTIONAL { ?book dbo:publisher ?publisher }

 # get the English title
 ?book rdfs:label ?name.
 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?name), 'en'))

 # get an English description, but not the text
 ?book rdfs:comment ?text .
 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?text), 'en'))

 # filter for books whose title contains "java"
 FILTER regex(str(?name) , "java", "i") . 
}
```

More efficient using the Virtuoso fulltext index predicate `bif:contains`:

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT * WHERE {
 ?book a dbo:Book .
 ?book dbo:author ?author . 
 OPTIONAL { ?book dbo:numberOfPages ?pages }
 OPTIONAL { ?book dbo:isbn ?isbn }
 OPTIONAL { ?book dbo:publisher ?publisher }

 # get the English title
 ?book rdfs:label ?name.
 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?name), 'en'))

 # get an English description, but not the text
 ?book rdfs:comment ?text .
 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?text), 'en'))


 # filter for books whose title contains "java"
 ?name bif:contains '"java"'
}
```

As a book might have multiple authors resp. publisher you might get duplicate rows, here `GROUP_BY` in combination with `GROUP_CONCAT` is the way to go (grouped by book):

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?book (group_concat(DISTINCT ?author; separator = ", ") as ?authors) (group_concat(DISTINCT ?publisher; separator = ", ") as ?publishers) (sample(?pages) as ?numPages) (sample(?isbn_tmp) as ?isbn) WHERE {
?book a dbo:Book .
?book dbo:author ?author . 
OPTIONAL { ?book dbo:numberOfPages ?pages }
OPTIONAL { ?book dbo:isbn ?isbn_tmp }
OPTIONAL { ?book dbo:publisher ?publisher }

# get the English title
?book rdfs:label ?name.
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?name), 'en'))

# get an English description, but not the text
?book rdfs:comment ?text .
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?text), 'en'))


# filter for books whose title contains "java"
?name bif:contains '"java"'
}
GROUP BY ?book
```